# How to calculate shopping cart total

Tags: reactjs, shopping-cart

I have been working on a webpage for a while and am having trouble calculating the total for my shopping list products. I have created a "price" variable in another file, as well as a state for "quantity" in another file, and would like to be able to multiply these two variables together to calculate the "Total". The code for doing this, I have is as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {
    getCartItems,
    removeCartItem,
    onSuccessBuy
} from '../../../_actions/user_actions';
import UserCardBlock from './Sections/UserCardBlock';
import { Result, Empty } from 'antd';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Paypal from '../../utils/Paypal';
function CartPage(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [Total, setTotal] = useState(0)
    const [ShowTotal, setShowTotal] = useState(false)
    const [ShowSuccess, setShowSuccess] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {

        let cartItems = [];
        if (props.user.userData && props.user.userData.cart) {
            if (props.user.userData.cart.length > 0) {
                props.user.userData.cart.forEach(item => {
                    cartItems.push(item.id)
                });
                dispatch(getCartItems(cartItems, props.user.userData.cart))
                    .then((response) => {
                        if (response.payload.length > 0) {
                            calculateTotal(response.payload)
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }, [props.user.userData])

    const calculateTotal = (cartDetail) => {
        let total = 0;

        cartDetail.map(props => {
            total += parseInt(props.productData.price, 10) * props.productData.price
        });

        setTotal(total)
        setShowTotal(true)
    }

    const removeFromCart = (productId) => {
        dispatch(removeCartItem(productId))
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.payload.cartDetail.length <= 0) {
                    setShowTotal(false)
                } else {
                    calculateTotal(response.payload.cartDetail)
                }
            })
    }

    const transactionSuccess = (data) => {
        dispatch(onSuccessBuy({
            cartDetail: props.user.cartDetail,
            paymentData: data
        }))
            .then(response => {
                if (response.payload.success) {
                    setShowSuccess(true)
                    setShowTotal(false)
                }
            })
    }

    const transactionError = () => {
        console.log('Paypal error')
    }

    const transactionCanceled = () => {
        console.log('Transaction canceled')
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '85%', margin: '3rem auto' }}>
            <h1>My Cart</h1>
            <div>

                <UserCardBlock
                    productData={props.location.state.data}
                    products={props.user.cartDetail}
                    removeItem={removeFromCart}
                />

              
                    <div style={{ marginTop: '3rem' }}>
                        <h2>Total amount: ${Total} </h2>
                    </div>
            </div>

            {/* Paypal Button */}

            {ShowTotal &&
                <Paypal
                    toPay={Total}
                    onSuccess={transactionSuccess}
                    transactionError={transactionError}
                    transactionCanceled={transactionCanceled}
                />
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartPage
```

Does this look correct? I am a little confused about what to put in the function before the arrows. I know I am doing something wrong... just not sure what. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the mapping look correct. are you concern about the mapping or the way you change the data? and maybe you can provide more code

Comment: sorry i cannot comment on your question since lack of rep